# Status bar in Android using Adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

Ive been doing apps for PC then I moved to Air and published it on Android devices and my question is can I set somewhere the value for statusbar color that comes with Material design? Im using Flash Professional CC

Comment: There's no API in AIR for this, you'll need to write an ANE (or find one).

Comment: If you need an ANE written drop me a line at airnativeextensions @ distriqt.com  and we'll put one together for you.